# How to fix problem 'Error when checking input: expected flatten_7_input to have shape (28, 28) but got array with shape (28, 3)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to create the NN using example on Tensorflow and feed it my own hand-written digit to predict right label but shape of array doesn't allow me to do this.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
      loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
      metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

path = 'C:/Users/pewdu/Desktop/third.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path)
new_img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28))
new_img = new_img / 255.0
print(new_img.shape) # it equals to (28,28,3)
prediction = model.predict(new_img)
```

So the error is:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_7_input to have shape (28, 28) but got array with shape (28, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Error` message says it all.

The model you initialized expects data in a `N x W x H` format where,

- N = Number of examples
- W = Width of the image
- H = Height of the image

When you are reading the image using `cv2.imread()`, you can see that the image size is given in `W x H x C` format where,

- W = Width of image
- H = Height of image
- C = Number of channels in the image (3 for RGB/BGR and 1 for GrayScale)

Your model is expecting a grayscale normalized image. And since you are sending only one image (single example), you need to reshape your image array by adding an axis at the front.

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
new_img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28))
new_img = new_img[:,:,0] / 255.0 # Take only first channel and normalize
new_img = np.expand_dims(new_img, axis=0) # Adding the dimension
print(new_img.shape) # it equals to (1, 28, 28)
prediction = model.predict(new_img)
```